# What is a rhetorical concession?

Tags: meaning

For context:

> The expression is used to bring up an unsatisfactory aspect of the seemingly agreed statement, thus it is a *rhetorical concession*.

It's explaining a construct in Chinese Mandarin.

Comment: @Mitch: I had a question about English so I posted it on english.stackexchange. Problem?

Comment: @Mitch: Fair enough. I'll delete all except my first comment, which I think stands as an acknowledgement that this wasn't a trivial matter to both establish *and* support with appropriate links.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the term, and I couldn't find the definition I eventually came up with by typing "define rhetorical concession" into Google. But it does seem to have an established meaning in some contexts.

Comment: @Mitch: Sounds like an excuse for excessive bureaucracy to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dPG0SbzYV0wC&pg=PA310&dq=%22rhetorical%20concession%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pro7T5GMAcis0QWrwNFs&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCDhQ#v=onepage&q=%22rhetorical%20concession%22&f=false) an explicit definition of a *rhetorical concession*.

In oratory, [rhetorical](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=rhetorical&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=qrs7T7qFHIa90QWh77Rs&ved=0CCIQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=eb2d694fa5cee7bd&biw=1359&bih=885) elements are only there for the sake of effect - *expressed in terms intended to persuade or impress*. So in the context of formal agreements, a rhetorical concession is one which actually concedes nothing of substance, yet gives the outward appearance of doing so.

In essence, it's like saying *"Yes, I accept what you say/want, **but**..."* - then proceeding to argue against the point you've apparently conceded. For example, this statement made on behalf of employers using badly-paid "sweat-shop" labour:

["Employers recognize that wages are essential to meeting employees' basic needs"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ut80-G862T8C&pg=PA162&dq=%22rhetorical%20concession%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yrk7T8bEN4HU0QXO1axt&ved=0CDAQ6AEwADgy#v=onepage&q=%22rhetorical%20concession%22&f=false)

...as a precursor to an "agreement" which concedes nothing in respect of working conditions/pay.

Comment: This makes my Chinese text book make much more sense, thank you. You might imagine how disheartening it is when the English is as indecipherable as the Chinese.

Comment: @Phil: In my neck of the woods, *Chinese* (language, culture, political intentions, etc.) are pretty much synonymous with *inherently inscrutable*, so it's kinda nice to see the English language fighting back with a (slightly) obscure phrase! :)

Comment: Has Greek been retired from this role? It used to standardly be, "It's Greek to me."

Comment: @Hexagon Tiling: In this current round of financial crisis it seems even the Greeks don't understand what they're doing. It's at least *possible* the Chinese do, even if the rest of the world doesn't understand it. Me, I just buy cheap electronic goodies from China on eBay, and hope the money ends up somewhere useful.